# Plotting $\left(1+\frac{1}{x^n}\right)^{x^n}$.

Tags: numerical-methods, graphing-functions, computational-mathematics, floating-point

When I plot the following function, the graph behaves strangely:

$$f(x) = \left(1+\frac{1}{x^{16}}\right)^{x^{16}}$$

While $\lim_{x\to +\infty} f(x) = e$ the graph starts to fade at $x \approx 6$. What's going on here? (plotted on my trusty old 32 bit PC.)
[image: Approximating e]

I guess it's because of computer approximation and loss of significant digits. So I started calculating the binary representation to see if this is the case. However in my calculations values of $x=8$ should still behave nicely.

If computer approximation would be the problem, then plotting this function on a 64 bit pc should evade the problem (a bit). I tried the Wolfram Alpha servers:

[image: Wolfram alpha]

The problem remains for the same values of $x$.

#### Questions

1. Could someone pinpoint the problem? What about the 32 vs 64 bit plot?
2. Is there a way to predict at which $x$-value the graph of the function below would start to fail?
   $$f_n(x) = \left(1+\frac{1}{x^n}\right)^{x^n}$$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

32bit vs. 64bit affects which integer types are used by default, which is of no interest here. Rather, the floting point computations are made (by default) with IEEE `double` type.
With this `double` precision (53 bit mantissa), the relative error of $(1+\frac1{x^{16}})$ is approximately $2^{-53}$. Raising to the $x^{16}$th power roughly multiplies the relative error, so it's  $\frac{8^{16}}{2^{53}}=2^{-5}$ (so absolutely $\approx 0.1$) for $x=8$, which does match your plot. At $x=9$ we can expect a relative error $\frac{9^{16}}{2^{53}}\approx0.2$, also consistent with your plot.
For $x>10$ we have $x^{16}>2^{53}$, so $(1+\frac1{x^{16}})\dot=1$, whereas righ tbefore this cutoff to a terminally too small $(1+\frac1{x^{16}})$, we have a longer phase of too big in the last and only bit, i.e., we essentially compute  $(1+\frac2{x^{16}})^{x^{16}}\approx e^2\approx 7.4$.

Answer (score 8):

Your problem is the finite precision of floating-point arithmetic. There are only so many numbers near $1$ that can be represented by the computer's floating-point format, and the larger your $x$ is, the more of the *difference* between $1$ and $1+\frac{1}{x^{16}}$ (which is what really matters when raising to a huge power) will be lost to rounding of the latter intermediate result.

In order to make precise calculations with such expressions possible, many programming languages provide primitive functions for computing $x\mapsto \log(1+x)$ and $x\mapsto e^x-1$ directly, *without* ever representing the intermediate result $1+x$ and $e^x$ explicitly.

To use this in your case you would rewrite
$$ (1+a)^b = e^{b \log (1+a)}$$
and write something like (e.g., in C, with `<math.h>`):

```
double x16 = pow(x,16);
double result = exp(log1p(1/x16) * x16);
```

---

You shouldn't expect any difference between computing on a 32-bit or a 64-bit machine, because even on "32-bit" machines the usual precision of floating point calculations is a 64-bit representation with about 16 significant digits of precision.

(Conversely, both 32-bit and 64-bit machines do support a 32-bit floating-point format, but operations on it are rarely any faster (in contrast to integer arithmetic, where 64-bit operations *are* slower on 32-bit machines), so in practice it is only used when one needs to store so many floating-point numbers that the combined size of them all becomes a concern.)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a plot using the (arbitrary precision) calculator Pari/GP. I use 200 dec digits precision as default in my computations and got this plot without oscillation up to x=20:

[image: bild]

I tried it so far up to x=256; no oscillation. See here the image up to x=128 (just to have the left increase visible)

[image: bild]